# How to deploy MVC 5 web application in IIS 8 server in Windows 8.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-deployment

I have developed MVC 5 web application in VS 2013 and I want to deploy that application in IIS 8 but its give me error as per given image.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're deploying to the default web site in IIS you can safely publish to the default website's directory and be up and running.

However, if you're deploying an ASP.NET MVC site to a subdirectory of the default site, or to a new directory on the server, you will need to create a new web site, or convert the subdirectory (when publishing under the default site) to an application.

If this is your first time setting up a site on IIS, Microsoft has documentation on the steps to follow in the learn section of ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've given IIS_IUSRS group READ permission to the wwwroot directory. (if it requires additional permissions, Read & Execute might be necessary).

There's also a IUSR that may need READ permission as well.

Comment: Right idea, but it looks like the OP is mapping the IIS site to a network location. IIS_IUSERS would need access to that network location, not wwwroot. Or, probably more accurately, the site would need to be configured so that IIS impersonates some user that has access to that network location, since you can't really give a local user access to a remote location.